# How do I find the exponential generating function of $a_n = (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}k \binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I'm learning Combinatorics and came across this question:

> Find the exponential generating function of the following series
>   $$a_n = (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}k \binom{n}{k}$$

I have problem with the part of the binom, because I know that when multiplying generating funciton the $n$ "part" is becoming $k \text{ or } n-k$ in the new sum from k to n (I hope you undertand what I mean). Anyway I would like to get some help

Comment: Hint: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k} = \sum\limits_{\ell=0}^n (n-\ell)\binom{n}{\ell} \implies \sum\limits_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}$

Comment: I understood the first equation but not the second one

Comment: change variable from $\ell$ to $k$ on RHS of 1st equation,  takes average and then apply binomial theorem.

Comment: oh I got it now, I'll try to work more on it, thanks. @achillehui

Comment: I think a more relevant hint for this problem would be $\displaystyle a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k \cdot (-1)^{n-k} \binom nk$.

Comment: @GregMartin with your approach I still have problem with the binom in the sum for the reason I've mentioned in my question

Comment: @achillehui My answer turned out to be $-xe^{-2x}$, is it right?

Comment: Compute the first few terms (or the entire Taylor series) for yourself and see.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}x^k.$$
Therefore
$$a_n=(-1)^n\frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^n\bigg|_{x=1}=(-1)^nn(1+1)^{n-1}=(-1)^n2^{n-1}n.$$
Thus 
$$\text{EGF}_{(a_n)}(x)=\frac12\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{n}{n!}(-2x)^n=\frac12\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-2x)^n}{(n-1)!}=-x\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-2x)^n}{n!}=-xe^{-2x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brutal-force solution:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{k!(n-k)!} \right) (-x)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{k!}(-x)^k \cdot \frac{1}{(n-k)!} (-x)^{n-k} \\
&= \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k!}(-x)^k \right) \left( \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{l!}(-x)^l \right) \\
&= (-x e^{-x})(e^{-x}) \\
&= -x e^{-2x}.
\end{align*}